# Debian 8 crashes once every few days

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, postgresql

I'm running Debian 8 on Linode 32 GB and once every few days the system crashes. This server is being used in productions and I need to find a solution ASAP

The only server running on Debian is Postgresql 9.5.3

Is there anyway I can find out why the system is crashing?

Here are the graphs of Linode that show the crash.

[image]

Journal file
http://pastebin.com/5FJ6eCsy

Comment: Read the journal entry for a crashed session...

Comment: I hope the journal goes far back enough. I think the crash happened about  14 hours a go. I have pasted the journal

Comment: That log doesn't start before the system was restarted and is thus worthless.

Comment: As noted, the logs are the place to look, but, note, your crash happened at exactly midday. Is it possible that that is relevant?

Comment: Do more graphs. There you may see if for example memory or nw traffic does not have a spike just before the crash. What does it mean "crash"? Hangs? Kernel panic? Reboots itself automatically? Maybe configure remote syslog, so you will have even the latest messages before the crash (local IO is usually hanged long before the system itself).